# Scale Image Maps with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, scale, imagemap

So I've this problem. I'm new to programming, keep that in mind.

What I'm trying to do: Scale some value in an image map using JQUERY.

What I thought: Image was wrapped at a width that it's its full. That would imply that it's the 100%. So if I take that number and then take the width the viewer is using, I *could* multiply the values on coord to always be on the track.

Some notes
(#mapa is the imagemap I'm using, #content is the general container I'm using as div to have everything together. 515 is the value of the natural width of the image.)
What I've done and it's not working:

```
var width = $('#content').width();
var exp = width * 515;
var mul = exp / 100; //I would do all in one line, but I'm always afraid I mess up.

$("area").each(function() {
var pairs = $(this).attr("coords").split(', ');
for (var i=0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    pairs[i] = pairs[i] * mul;
    }
$(this).html('coords', pairs.join);
});
```

So...How any suggestion/advice/plugin?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To create a scaling factor, multiply by the desired (end) width and divide by the original (start) width.

Comment: Rule of three:
If 515 is the 100% of the current image, the current width is...
Current Width x 100% all that divided by original width.

So far that's good, but the code still doesn't work. The coords just doesn't change. ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).html('coords', pairs.join);
```

should be

```
$(this).attr('coords', pairs.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a probable problem here:

```
var pairs = $(this).attr("coords").split(', ');
```

should *possibly* be

```
var pairs = $(this).attr("coords").split(',');
```

in case there should be an area definition with no space after the comma(s).

Then the other, more serious one:

```
$(this).html('coords', pairs.join);
```

should be

```
$(this).attr('coords', pairs.join(','))
```

I just implemented a "scaleAreas" function using your code as the very basis and it is working perfectly and your initial work saved my day.